# How to apply setText method using the Map, where my JTextField element is already allocated in the Map?

Tags: java, swing, dictionary

I have this following `SSCCE` where i can not re-call the `currentComponents.get(status)`  to have .setText() method. How can i setText using the Map method?

**After pressing button a the text field is still empty**

[image]

Test.java:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import layout.SpringUtilities;

public class Test {

  private static String status = null;
  private static Map<String, JTextField> currentComponents = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
  private static JPanel dialog;

  public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JLabel label = new JLabel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DialogLoginsetup();

    frame.add(dialog);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  /* Dialog part 1 */
  private static void DialogLoginsetup() {    

    JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();
    configPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 2, 2));

    try {
      Loginsetup(configPanel);
    } catch (IOException io) {
      io.printStackTrace();
    }

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Setup: "));

    dialog = new JPanel();   
    dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    dialog.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    dialog.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    dialog.add(configPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
  }  

  /* Dialog part 2 */
  private static JTextField serverTextField;
  public static void Loginsetup(JPanel configPanel) throws IOException {
    JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
    loginPanel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());

    currentComponents.put("serverTextField", new JTextField());

    // server
    JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    serverTextField= new JTextField();
    serverLabel.setLabelFor(serverTextField);
    loginPanel.add(serverLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    loginPanel.add(serverTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    serverTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {      
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
        status = "serverTextField";
      }

      public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {

      }
    });

    //Layout the panel.
    //SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(loginPanel,
                                //1, 2,         //rows, cols
                                //6, 6,        //initX, initY
                                //6, 6);

    configPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    configPanel.add(loginPanel);
    configPanel.add(loadAZ());
  }

  /* Dialog part 3 */
  public static JPanel loadAZ() {
    JPanel az = new JPanel();   
    az.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(11, 11, 11, 11));
    az.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,12));
    String[] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" , "k" , "l", "m", "n",
                         "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "-", "_"
    };

    JButton[] ka = new JButton[28];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 28; i++) {  
      ka[i] = new JButton(alphabet[i]);
      ka[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   
          String one = e.getActionCommand();          
          System.out.println("Something is pressed, which should be added to: " + status);   

          if (one.equals("a")) {            
            //currentComponents.get(status).setText();
            JComponent component = currentComponents.get(status);
            ((JTextComponent) component).setText("works");        // Did not worked
          } else if(one.equals("b")) {
          } else {            
          }
        }
      });
      az.add(ka[i]);      
    }
    return az;
  }  

}
```

**Follow up:**

Try 1: [FAIL]

```
private static Map<String, JTextField> currentComponents = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
currentComponents.put("serverTextField", new JTextField());
JTextField goal = currentComponents.get("serverTextField");
goal.setText("1");
```

Try 2: [FAIL]

```
JTextField goal = (JTextField) (JTextComponent) (Object) "serverTextField";
goal.setText("1");
```

Try 3: [FAIL]

```
JTextField goal = new JTextField();
goal.setName("serverTextField");
goal.setText("1");
```

Try 4: [**OK**]

```
private static List<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
list.add(serverTextField); // #define JTextField serverTextField = new JTextField();
JTextField goal = list.get(0);
goal.setText("1"); // Works
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can get a component out of the currentComponents map and call setText on it?

Comment: What is the purpose of the currentComponents Map? I have to criticize this question as being very short on important details, and this SSCCE for not complying with SSCCE protocol. Why MyLabel and not JLabel, and same for other derived classes?

Comment: @YumYumYum I don't understand for why is there Map<String, JComponent>, please what do you really expected :-), because JButtons (with minor changes) array could be works and without another Map ...

Comment: @mKorbel: none answers here actually worked, typecast or etc. I need to map it because i have forms which will be fill in by touch pad. So A to Z buttons and 0 - 1 buttons. Once i select any textfield those keypad will be wake up. And add the values. Therefore to reduce the button and code i was finding the Map best, which is however not working yet.

Comment: @YumYumYum the same way how you set alphabet[i], you can setActionCommand (JButton click returns defined via getActionCommand) or [putClientProperty](http://example.com), Map<String, JComponent> should be useless in this moment, because I miss there PropertyChangeListener,

Comment: @mKorbel: 1) `setActionCommand` is done via alphabet which is not relevant for this 2) `Map<String, JTextField>` with `PropertyChangeListener` maybe not relevant because it is useful when i want to listen on the *STYLE*, here i am trying value swapping only (correct me if i am wrong plz :) ). 3) Example: a) lets say you have 900 text fields b) you have only 24 character buttons and 0 to 9 numeric entry buttons all via touch (no keyboard) c) you need to first touch JTextField and use the touch pad. In that case i still see the Map<String, JTextField> is the better d) however still not working

Comment: @YumYumYum simple use the JTable, DefaultTableModel returns Vector<Vector<Object> and then this touch could be good for filtering or sorting Objects from TableModel to the View, there you can put Icons by default, once time you loading all relevant data to the Model (900 text fields) and via button(touch (no keyboard)) you can manage very complicating registrations system

Comment: @YumYumYum easiest will be to tell what do you want to create :-)

Comment: @mKorbel: Above screenshot you can see the user interface main buttons. That remain same but in my case i will have JTextField (sometimes 10, or 20 or 900 depending on the scenario and layout restrictions or sometimes only 1 as shown above). All those will stay inside one JPanel. The only tracking i need to apply is once JTextField gets focus, any button press will add values to the focused JTextField, that is the goal (where i was using Map and failing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare:

```
private static Map<String, JTextField> currentComponents 
    = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
```

Since `JComponent` does not have method `setText(...)`. In your example you are only using `JTextField` in this map. If you plan to put other components also into this map, use a cast, as others suggested.

Comment: You could typecast the return value from currentComponents

Comment: @Howard: Sorry i tried this, but still no luck setText does not get set.

Answer (score 1):

((JTextComponent) currentComponents.get(...)).setText(...)

Comment: Without checking first that it's a text component?

Comment: that's what I'd do. If it's not a text component, do you want to raise an exception or just fail silently? By not checking, you ensure that an exception will happen if it isn't

Answer (score 1):

Where the obvious answer is to use a cast, I would say: get rid of the map. Just pass the text field to your `ActionListener` (as a parameter, or using a final variable, ... ) and remove that map. Since your listener only updates one component, pass it to the listener iso using instanceof's and static maps.

Further, your

```
ka[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   
          String one = e.getActionCommand();          
          System.out.println("Something is pressed, which should be added to: " + status);   

          if (one.equals("a")) {            
            currentComponents.get(status).setText();
          } else if(one.equals("b")) {
          } else {            
          }
        }
      });
```

code has a few issues

1. I do not see the call to `setActionCommand` on your button, so I fear the `getActionCommand` will not return the expected result
2. there is no need for the gigantic if you are constructing if you want to update the text in the field with the text of the button. Set the text of the button as action command, and append that text to the field. Far easier then writing 26 if-else statements

Comment: 1) returns well 2) I do not only have 1 JTextField, i have scenario where i will have 900 JTextFields, so based on focus i have to apply the value of JButton to JTextFields